# is it safe to reuse the public key in NTRUEncrypt?

Tags: ntru

Looking at https://github.com/tbuktu/libntru/blob/master/src/ntru.h, there are some functions that deal with having multiple public keys with the same private key. I don't believe I need such functionality but it makes me suspect that it might be required. Basically, I want to know if it is OK to reuse the same keypair in NTRUEncrypt for a number of different key exchange operations.

Comment: In general for public-key encryption it must be safe to reuse the public key --- the cryptosystem must be secure against any poly-time bounded adversary, who can encrypt polynomially many messages. Do you mean "reuse" in this sense, or in another sense?